# Approach for executing stored procedure on .NET 4 application

Tags: stored-procedures, .net-4.0

My .NET 4 console application has to execute a SQL Server 2005 stored procedure to retrieve desired data set. Since I've been using some .NET1.1 or .NET2 technology with my legacy system for a long time and not familiar with new technology. I was wondering if there's any new technology is recommended in this scenario? There are some terms like Entity Framework 4, LINQ, etc... making me confused. Hope the community can advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF, LINQ - these are good things but they are also a bit advanced.  Crawl, walk, run, is my suggestion.

The classic approach will still work - create a SqlConnection class, create a SqlAdapter, set it's command properties and execute it.

Next step would be to create a strongly typed data set and define your data adapaters within it - get familiar with how that works before moving on to EF (which builds on the concept).

Always good to learn the plumbing. :)

Comment: @Greebo, using System.Data.SqlClient works for me. However, just want to know if EF, LINQ will make the application more easy to maintain on object-relational impedance mismatch aspect.

Comment: @Stan - most people don't even know the *term* impedance mismatch. It sounds like you're qualified to evaluate EF, LINQ-to-SQL, NHibernate, etc. yourself. :)

Comment: Ok I take it back - by all means get into EF and linq! ;)  In a nutshell, EF enables you to bypass a lot of the plumbing, it handles all the data layer machinations and gives you ready made objects to use (or, with code first, you create your objects and the db is built for you based on your POCOs, and fluent-api lets go hybrid with that concept).  LINQ is a query language for .NET - it works a lot like SQL in many ways, and coupled with EF it can write some quite elegant data access calls on its own based on what you tell it you want.